# tmux color profile (-2) when starting in iterm2 or other places

Tags: tmux, iterm2, terminfo

I am using iTerm2 with tmux and invoke it by doing:

```
tmux -CC new -s MySession
```

I was wondering if there is any use in doing something like `-2` when invoking tmux in iTerm2, or if that takes care of all of the color-profiles,

```
tmux -2 -CC new -s MySession
```

Actually, to take that a step further, when does the `-2` option have any significance? It seems like often when I invoke tmux on a linux server that the profile is already doing `-2` (perhaps in the tmux.conf) -- is there a way to know if `-2` will affect the default tmux session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `tmux` can determine (via `$TERM` and terminfo/termcap/etc) that your terminal supports 256 colors, `-2` isn't necessary. The option allows `tmux` to *assume* 256 colors are support when the terminal doesn't advertise the capability correctly.

Comment: termcap can't provide this information